# Is there any way to reduce the APK size within 5-10 MB after adding Zoom Android SDK?

Tags: android, zoom-sdk

I have created a demo app, where implemented Zoom Android SDK. This demo is running successfully but after adding Zoom SDK, the APK size is getter than 50 MB. I have added only the “abiFilters” “arm64-v8a”, “armeabi-v7a”. After that the APK size is not reduced. Is there any way to reduce the APK size within 5-10 MB after adding Zoom SDK?

Comment: if you want to launch your app in Play store than make bundle

Comment: Thank you, its really a good suggestion, but after making app release bundle, the size is 45 MB. Only 5 MB size has reduced. But I need to reduce more size.

Comment: Can you show app analyze screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to shrink your code setting minifyEnabled true and shrinkResource true in your build.gradle

[Android developers link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#shrink-code)

Comment: Thank you for giving this suggestion, but this solution not reduced my APK size. Is this really possible to reduce the APK size after using the zoom SDK?

Comment: After implementing Zoom android sdk and publishing the bundle, i am not able to install the app from playstore. It says can't install <app name>. Try again  and if it still doesn't work, see common ways to fix. I added the splits block to create the apk and useLegacyPackaging true. I can download the universal apk from play console and it works. But not directly from the playstore.